# How to improve performance when opening an external image?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is how I am opening an external image right now (Angular):

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: imageURL.full,
  responseType: "blob"
}).then(function(res) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(res.data);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      canvas.loadMainImage(e.target.result);
      $rootScope.started = true;
      $rootScope.uploaded = true;
      $rootScope.changeStyling();
    };
  },
  function(res) {
    console.log("For some reasons it failed to open", res);
  });
```

How I am adding it to canvas:

// canvas.loadMainImage function

```
fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(img) {

  //img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

  object = new fabric.Image(img, canvas.imageStatic);
  object.name = 'mainImage';

  if (width && height) {
    object.width = width;
    object.height = height;
  }

  canvas.mainImage = object;

  canvas.fabric.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    if (obj.name == 'mainImage') {
      canvas.fabric.remove(obj);
    }
  });

  canvas.fabric.add(object);
  object.top = -0.5;
  object.left = -0.5;
  object.moveTo(0);

  canvas.fabric.setHeight(object.height);
  canvas.fabric.setWidth(object.width);

  canvas.original.height = object.height;
  canvas.original.width = object.width;

  $rootScope.canvaswidth = canvas.original.width;
  $rootScope.canvasheight = canvas.original.height;

  $rootScope.calculateImageType(canvas.original.width, canvas.original.height);

  if ($rootScope.gridadded) {
    $rootScope.removeGrid();
    $rootScope.addGrid();
  }

  if (!dontFit) {
    canvas.fitToScreen();
  }

  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('editor.mainImage.loaded');
  });

  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
});
```

It works kind of well except for those situations then an image is 3000x3000, 4000x4000, 5000x5000 or of bigger dimensions. How could I improve my solution for such cases? Maybe, web workers could do?

Comment: you can try use gulp-minimg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question title references performance, I assume that's the aspect of your code that you want to improve. There are a couple of approaches that may be available to you.

1. Optimize the image. As Thanh suggested, if you have control over the images, you can optimize them with compression. The dimensions would remain the same, but the level of detail would be less (perhaps imperceptibly less, depending on the compression technique). The browser would then be able to load and display the images more quickly.
2. Modify the user interface. You change the user's perception of the page through modifications to the interface. A trivial example that may be available to you is to switch to progressive JPEG encoding. This encoding allows the browser to quickly render a rough (typically pixelated) version of the image and then fill in the details. Users see some form of the image right away, so they perceive the page to be faster. More drastic options are adding progress indicators and then removing them only after the image render is complete. Users don't see the image right away, but at least the page looks like it's busy doing something meaningful instead of being (apparently) stuck waiting for an image.

These two options are not exclusive.